# Obtener la salida de system sin usar popen en c, windows

Tags: c, windows, stdout

gracias por adelantado a las personas que respondieron a esta pregunta

recientemente he estado creando algo parecido a un ide de nasm (Netwide Assembler) donde linkeo el codigo con la funcion system:

```
    EXE exe=InitEnsamblado(rutas);
     system(exe.linkeado);//esto seria algo asi como
    //system(c:\flush\flushcompiler\flush\ide\bin\nasm\nasm.exe -f win32 Asm.asm -o program.o)
```

Buscando en internet logre crear este codigo sobre popen:

```
 EXE exe=InitEnsamblado(rutas);
FILE *exeEns = popen("c:\\flush\\flushcompiler\\flush\\ide\\bin\\nasm\\nasm.exe -f win32 Asm.asm -o program.o", "r");
if(exeEns == NULL) {
  printf("Could not open pipe.\n");
  return 0;
}
char buf[256];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), exeEns) != 0) {
fgets(buf, 20, exeEns);
printf("Ensamblado:\nbuffer:%s\n", buf);
}
pclose(exeEns);
```

Funciona con el comando pause u otros, lo lee y lo guarda en el archivo y lo leo la salida correctamente, pero al ejecutar el linker los errores o la salida del programa aparecen en la consola pero parece que  no se guardan en el archivo
(Para ver de lo que hablo en el programa remplaza  `"c:\\flush\\flushcompiler\\flush\\ide\\bin\\nasm\\nasm.exe -f win32 Asm.asm -o program.o"`por `"c:\\flush\\flushcompiler\\flush\\ide\\bin\\nasm\\nasm.exe -fwin32 Asm.asm -o program.o"` )

Lo que quiero es que si el linker me imprime algun error en el codigo o un error de sintaxis, guardarlo en una variable de tipo char* y tratarlo posteriormente en el resto del programa

Quiero evitar el uso de tuberias porque son muy complejas y no les entiendo nada, asi como ya vi que al parecer no funcionan para mis propositos
Gracias por su ayuda y compresion :)

Comment: `popen` redirige `stdout` a para que tu lo leas. Pero probablemente los errores se envien por `stderr`, asi que tendras que investigar como leer el `stdout` y `stderr` de un proceso.

Comment: Hola, primero que todo gracias por responder

Comment: Parece que no hay suficiente informacion para leer el stderr de un proceso externo o hijo, podrias ayudarme ;-)